# Effect of mixing commas and semicolons in javascript variable declaration

Tags: javascript

In the code below, `horiz` is being declared and then run through a for loop which fills it with empty arrays. Same for `verti` on second line etc. Does the `"var"` declaration only apply to `horiz` (i.e the semicolon breaks the `"var"` declaration) or does the `"var"` declaration also initialize `horiz`, `verti`, `here`, `path` and `unvisited`?

```
var horiz =[]; for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) horiz[j]= [],
    verti =[]; for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) verti[j]= [],
    here = [Math.floor(Math.random()*x), Math.floor(Math.random()*y)],
    path = [here],
    unvisited = [];
```

Edit: Added full function here for clarity. The variables in the function are not global or are being initialized outside the function.

Edit 2: Code is from here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation#JavaScript

```
function maze(x,y) {
    var n=x*y-1;
    if (n<0) {alert("illegal maze dimensions");return;}
    var horiz =[]; for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) horiz[j]= [],
        verti =[]; for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) verti[j]= [],
        here = [Math.floor(Math.random()*x), Math.floor(Math.random()*y)],
        path = [here],
        unvisited = [];
    for (var j = 0; j<x+2; j++) {
        unvisited[j] = [];
        for (var k= 0; k<y+1; k++)
            unvisited[j].push(j>0 && j<x+1 && k>0 && (j != here[0]+1 || k !=     here[1]+1));
    }
    while (0<n) {
        var potential = [[here[0]+1, here[1]], [here[0],here[1]+1],
            [here[0]-1, here[1]], [here[0],here[1]-1]];
        var neighbors = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (unvisited[potential[j][0]+1][potential[j][1]+1])
                neighbors.push(potential[j]);
        if (neighbors.length) {
            n = n-1;
            next= neighbors[Math.floor(Math.random()*neighbors.length)];
            unvisited[next[0]+1][next[1]+1]= false;
            if (next[0] == here[0])
                horiz[next[0]][(next[1]+here[1]-1)/2]= true;
            else 
                verti[(next[0]+here[0]-1)/2][next[1]]= true;
            path.push(here = next);
        } else 
            here = path.pop();
    }
    return {x: x, y: y, horiz: horiz, verti: verti};
}
```

Comment: Did you run this code and see what values the variables have? Don't run to stackoverflow asking questions like this. Tinker with the code. Remove commas, add semicolons or the other way round and see what happens. You'll learn much more from it than from a dry answer.

Comment: Yes I did run the code, and what I want to understand is theoretical and it can't be figured out by replacing commas and semicolons -- which I did already. I now know that the first line is initializing "horiz" and running the for loop to fill "horiz", second line is doing the same for "verti" etc.. but the question for me now is **is the "var" being applied to only the horiz variable and being broken upon encountering the semicolon or does it initialize "verti", "here", "path" and "unvisited" also.

Answer (score 1):

```
var horiz =[]; //variable declaration

for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) //for loop start
  horiz[j]= [], verti =[]; //variable declaration 
//for loop end


for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) //for loop start
    verti[j]= [], here = [Math.floor(Math.random()*x), Math.floor(Math.random()*y)], path = [here], unvisited = []; //variable declaration
//for loop end
```

You're probably getting confused due to the missing braces

```
var horiz =[]; //variable declaration

for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) {
  horiz[j]= [], verti =[]; //variable declaration
}


for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) {
    verti[j]= [], here = [Math.floor(Math.random()*x), Math.floor(Math.random()*y)], path = [here], unvisited = []; //variable declaration
}
```

Comment: Why was "horiz" defined with a var but not "verti"? Why is "verti" being initialized so many times inside the first for loop? Why is "here", "path" and "unvisited" being overwritten so many times inside the second loop? I'm sorry but I don't think you are correct... I've been reading on the comma operator for javascript (but still confused!) and will post the link here soon.

Comment: @a20 Considering this is a code snippet from a block of code,"var horiz =[]" is declaring horiz as an empty array,"horiz[j]= []" is declaring j th element of horiz as an empty array,"verti =[]" is declaring verti as an empty array(probably global, if not declared earlier in code),"verti[j]= []" is declaring j th element of verti as an empty array,"here" is an array with two elements(probably global, if ... code),"path = [here]" is declared as an array with first element "here"(probably global, if...code),"unvisited = []" is declaring "unvisited" empty array(probably global, if...code)

Comment: There are no other global declarations, this "var .. " line is the very first line doing the declarations. I've editted my code to include the full code for clarity. Your reply didn't answer my comment at all. I know javascript and there is no reason to **initialize** an array **inside a for loop multiple times**. Your interpretation is wrong. Please read my first comment and understand what I'm trying to say first.

Comment: Note Legionar's answer below. It's the same conclusion I've come to also, but still waiting for more proof on it. In the meantime, I hope you realise that your explanation is wrong, and three other people also upvoted you(!!). Please stop giving advice on things you are not knowledgible on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors and you should check your console to see them. So, your variables aren't declared - only `horiz` is declared. The semicolon after `var horiz =[]` will end the declaration of other variables. So this code:

```
var horiz =[]; for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) horiz[j]= [],
    verti =[]; for (var j= 0; j<x+1; j++) verti[j]= [],
    here = [Math.floor(Math.random()*x), Math.floor(Math.random()*y)],
    path = [here],
    unvisited = [];
```

Change to this:

```
var horiz = [],
    verti = [],
    here = [Math.floor(Math.random()*x), Math.floor(Math.random()*y)],
    path = [here],
    unvisited = [];

for (var j = 0; j < x + 1; j++) {
    horiz[j] = [];
}

for (var j = 0; j < x + 1; j++) {
    verti[j] = [];
}
```

Also I suggest you to use braces `{ ... }`for better readability.

Comment: Not my code, updated the original post. So my assumption is correct then, var is only initializing the first variable. Any link or theoretical source to back this up? I'm thinking the guy who originally wrote that function looks to be quite advanced and he/she wouldn't have made such an obvious error.

Comment: Yes, your assumption with `var` is ok. About declaring variables you can find all info at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp. I don't know, if he/she has advanced knowledges in JS, but that declaration on that website is totally incorrect and won't work at all.